# Loop and mistake error in hangman game

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

```
print('Welcome to Hangman! Guess the mystery word with less than 6 mistakes!')

while True:
    words=['table','chair','pencil','stapler','pen','computer',
   'printer','cable','books','shelf']

    alphabet=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g,','h','i','j','k','l','m','n',
    'o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']

    number=input('Please enter an integer number (0<=number<10) 
    to choose the word in the list:')    

    if number=='':
        print('Empty input!')
        continue
    elif number in alphabet:
        print('Input must be an integer!')
        continue

    number=int(number)

    if number<0 or number>9:
        print('Index is out of range!')
        continue

    elif 0<=number<10:
        break

words2=[]
words2.extend(words[number])


print('The length of the word is: ',len(words2))

i=0
j=0
while j<6 or i!=len(words2):
```

The game continues even after 6 mistakes(mistakes=j and letter in word=i)

```
    letter=input('Please enter the letter you guess: ')

    for alphabet in letter:
        if alphabet in words2:
            print('The letter is in the word.')
            i=i+1

            if i==len(words2):
                    print('You have found the mystery word. You win!')
                    print('Goodbye!')
                    break
```

The previous break is not working. Is it cause it only breas the FOR loop and not while loop?

```
            else:
            continue 



        elif alphabet not in words2:
            if letter not in alphabet:
                print('You need to input a single alphabetic character!')
            elif letter not in words2:
                j=j+1
                print('The letter is not in the word.')
```

HELLO! This is a hangman game that I am writing. I am facing two problems

Thank you

I looked up similar questions but none of them had the specific solution and I have also done my best to edit this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think your while test is the mistake

```
while j<6 or i!=len(words2):
```

Should be

```
while j<6 and i!=len(words2):
```

Comment: hi! Did you edit my while loop in your 2 sentence? Looks the same. Is there another reason?

Comment: @vishal: **and** instead of **or** :)

Comment: Hi robert. if i put 'and' then both the conditions have to be true. I was working with either of the conditions being true i=length of word or j=6 mistakes

Comment: won't 'or' be a better choice in that case?

Comment: The answer will work for only 6 letter word won't it?

Comment: Just to answer your question. AND is the correct state. You want to continue the loop while they've made less than 6 guesses AND they have not yet guessed the right answer.

Comment: thank you. Now i understand. I will accept the answer in 2 minutes because I cannot do it before that

Comment: Something to point out, is 'break' will only break out of the inner most loop. Not any surrounding loops.

Comment: @deadchex GOT IT! did you -1 my question?

Comment: No. Just pointing out how breaks work.. Some thing I've been bitten on before

Comment: Yeah you guys on stack flow really explain things well. Helps a lot :)